# BLE STM BlueNrg characteristic max size and max characteristic per service

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32

I have two issues with my BlueNRG-MS BLE module which I'm not really sure if this is intended design:

1. The maximum size of a characteristic cannot exceed 20 bytes. If I create a characteristic that is e.g. 32 bytes long, although I can read the whole 32 bytes, when the characteristic is notified (updated) by the BLE, only 20 bytes are transmitted. I've found some references which confirm this, but I havent found a reasonable explanation.
2. I can only add 2 characteristics to one service. This seems rather odd and I wonder if there's a limiting configuration parameter which I'm missing. If I add 3 characteristics to one service, only the first two get added. I'm using the STM LightBlue App for debugging.

**Update**: The return value of the `aci_gatt_add_char()` function is `ERR_UNSPECIFIED_ERROR`
It seems like there are others having the same issue
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkYh6/another-question-about-bluenrg-errunspecifiederror

Comment: The first problem can be solved by increasing the MTU https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000M8ySaSAJ/how-can-i-change-mtu-value-on-my-bluenrgm2-module

Comment: It seems to be chip dependant, according to this answer https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkXaRSAV/stm32l4xx-how-to-increase-bluenrgms-attmtu the MTU for BlueNRG-MS chips cannot be modified

Comment: I found the newer version of your chip. You might want to add the usage of BlueNRG-MS to your question

Comment: Does anyone have an idea what the cause of the `ERR_UNSPECIFIED_ERROR` could be when I try to add more than 2 characteristics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like in my case the problem was caused by the `max_attr_records` parameter of the `aci_gatt_add_serv()` call.
I haven't found a clear specification so far, but you seem to need 1 for the service itself and and my case (with the `CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY` flag set) +3 for each characteristic. So it works for now, still if someone has a clear insight in how to determine the `max_attr_records` please let me know. Also, setting it too high also doesn't work, but here I haven't found an explanation so far.

Comment: A characteristic needs at least 2 attributes (1 for declaration and 1 for value). It requires 1 additional attribute if the characteristic has the Notify (/Indicate) property, and 1 additional attribute for each descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Just face the same problem, don't know why ST make it so hard to use.
I'm using Bluenrg-LP and BLE_SerialPort example project.

I Changed 5 to 7 and set .chr_count = 4. Now I can create 4 characteristic in serial_port_chars[]. Also checked with LightBlue App.

/* Number of characteristics attributes requests */
#define NUM_APP_GATT_CHAR_ATTRIBUTES_CONF (7) /* attributes for serial port service characteristics */